# Python 2.7 several conditions for lambda? Elif?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coreml, turi-create

During the guide I followed from I have an error: [CoreMD using Python](https://www.appcoda.com/core-ml-model-with-python/)

Need to create a simple dataset following the guide. The only difference between guide is made by me:

```
data["personalityType"] = data["path"].apply(     lambda path: "Enfj" if "enfj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Enfp" if "enfp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Entj" if "entj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Entp" if "entp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Esfj" if "esfj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Esfp" if "esfp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Estj" if "estj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Estp" if "estp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Infj" if "Infj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Infp" if "infp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Intj" if "intj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Intp" if "intp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Isfj" if "isfj" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Isfp" if "isfp" in path
                                             else lambda path: "Istj" if "istj" in path
                                             else "Istp")
```

instead of:

```
data["foodType"] = data["path"].apply(lambda path: "Rice" if "rice"
```

The error log in Terminal:

> python classifier.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "classifier.py", line 20, in
>   
>       data.save("ptype.sframe")
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/sframe.py",
>   line 2808, in save
>       raise ValueError("Unsupported format: {}".format(format))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/cython/context.py",
>   line 49, in **exit**
>       raise exc_type(exc_value)
>
> RuntimeError: Exception in python callback function evaluation:
>
> TypeError("Cannot convert type 'function' into flexible type.",):
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "turicreate/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 427, in
>   turicreate.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda    File
>   "turicreate/cython/cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 172, in
>   turicreate.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_simple
>   File "turicreate/cython/cy_flexible_type.pyx", line 1306, in
>   turicreate.cython.cy_flexible_type.process_common_typed_list    File
>   "turicreate/cython/cy_flexible_type.pyx", line 1251, in
>   turicreate.cython.cy_flexible_type._fill_typed_sequence    File
>   "turicreate/cython/cy_flexible_type.pyx", line 1636, in
>   turicreate.cython.cy_flexible_type._ft_translate
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert type 'function' into flexible type.

What the problem could be, because I can't run my classifier.py with Python 2.7

Comment: It’s definitely in cause of Lambda , but i don’t know how to solve it for 10+ varieties

Comment: Does it work if you pass it a regular function instead of that huge mess of nested lambdas?

Comment: Not really xD trying to use elif

Comment: Would you consider a simple function to replace the mess of nested `if` / `else` ?

Comment: @jpp I am not so familial with python syntax :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your nested `if` / `else` construct with a simple function.

Below is an example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['enfpD', 'iNfp', 'sadintj', 'abc']})

choices = {'enfp', 'entj' , 'entp', 'esfj' , 'esfp',
           'estj', 'estp', 'infj', 'infp', 'intj',
           'intp', 'isfj', 'isfp', 'istj'}

def changer(x):
    match = next((c for c in choices if c in x), None)
    if match:
        return match.title()
    else:
        return 'Istp'

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(changer)

print(df)

#       A
# 0  Enfp
# 1  Istp
# 2  Intj
# 3  Istp
```

Comment: I give up. Finally, I have an issue of 104 if else statements and this is the only solution :) Thank you! However, could you please help to solve another similar example, because I don't see the connection between choices (16 paths/names... got this.) and DataFrame... Only 4? What does it mean A variable?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182760/python-stack-overflow-104-if-statements-is-defx-the-only-solution-to-opti

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect syntax:

```
     lambda path: "Enfj" if "enfj" in path   
else lambda path: "Enfp" if "enfp" in path
else lambda path: "Entj" if "entj" in path
else lambda path: "Entp" if "entp" in path
else lambda path: "Esfj" if "esfj" in path
else lambda path: "Esfp" if "esfp" in path
else lambda path: "Estj" if "estj" in path
else lambda path: "Estp" if "estp" in path
else lambda path: "Infj" if "Infj" in path
else lambda path: "Infp" if "infp" in path
else lambda path: "Intj" if "intj" in path
else lambda path: "Intp" if "intp" in path
else lambda path: "Isfj" if "isfj" in path
else lambda path: "Isfp" if "isfp" in path
else lambda path: "Istj" if "istj" in path
else "Istp"
```

Correct syntax:

```
    lambda path: "Enfj" if "enfj" in path 
else("Enfp" if "enfp" in path
else("Entj" if "entj" in path
else("Entp" if "entp" in path
else("Esfj" if "esfj" in path
else("Esfp" if "esfp" in path
else("Estj" if "estj" in path
else("Estp" if "estp" in path
else("Infj" if "Infj" in path
else("Infp" if "infp" in path
else("Intj" if "intj" in path
else("Intp" if "intp" in path
else("Isfj" if "isfj" in path
else("Isfp" if "isfp" in path
else("Istj" if "istj" in path
else "Istp")))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your function returns a string if the first evaluation is true, otherwise it returns a lambda function, as it does not call this function.  Because of this a type error is thrown as a SFrame column cannot hold different types (string or function).  I would highly recommend defining a long if else function and passing this to the apply or a similar, more efficient function.

jpp's code modified for simplicity and to use Turicreate

```
import turicreate as tc

sf = tc.SFrame({'path': ['enfpD', 'iNfp', 'sadintj', 'abc']})

choices = ['enfp', 'entj' , 'entp', 'esfj' , 'esfp',
           'estj', 'estp', 'infj', 'infp', 'intj',
           'intp', 'isfj', 'isfp', 'istj']

def changer(x):
    for choice in choices:
        if choice in x:
            return choice.capitalize() 
    return 'Istp'

sf['personalityType'] = sf['path'].apply(changer)

print(sf)

#+---------+-----------------+
#|   path  | personalityType |
#+---------+-----------------+
#|  enfpD  |       Enfp      |
#|   iNfp  |       istp      |
#| sadintj |       Intj      |
#|   abc   |       Istp      |
#+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm just starting to learn Python and could you help me please to make it clear in a similar example of mine? Now I have much more samples, and It's a problem for if/else statement ))
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182760/python-stack-overflow-104-if-statements-is-defx-the-only-solution-to-opti

Comment: @Oleksandr Even though you are using TuriCreate instead of Pandas the code in app's should still work.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Oleksandr I modified jpp's code to be simpler and to use turicreate.

Comment: where? Because I’ve found your similar topic of your:  { x for x in list if x.split in output.split()} but I have only errors if to create list with all items: list=[„ars1”,”ars2”,...]

Comment: Its in the process of being peer reviewed, I'll just add it to my post

Comment: I've used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452760/turi-create-please-use-dropna-to-drop-rows/50456223#50456223 
It helped a lot! Thank you! However, I don't see the logic of these random paths in SFrame.